# exception error: bad argument in function

Tags: erlang

When I compile my erlang code then exception "error: bad argument
     in function" shows in following line

```
Packet =[<<0:8, TokenLength, Token, PayloadLength, Payload>>],
```

The above code is part of my code.
Please someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably this happens because `Token` and `Payload` are binaries, not integers.

When constructing a binary like this, everything is assumed to be a 1-byte integer unless specified otherwise.  To insert `Token` and `Payload` into the binary being constructed, use the `/binary` suffix:

```
Packet =[<<0:8, TokenLength, Token/binary, PayloadLength, Payload/binary>>],
```